# How to disable multiple devices from Windows device manager at once using Command Prompt or Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, command-prompt, wmic

First of all, I hope everyone is very well and healthy today and always.
My question is about how to disable multiple devices from the Windows device manager at once using Command Prompt or Powershell...

I tried to do it the way I suggest below, trying to find a common variable for all of them, the variable I found but the command I used to try to disable them all at the same time did not, could any of you shed some light on how to get the result that desire?

To find the common variable between them:

```
"wmic nic get Availability, CreationClassName, Index, Name, NetEnabled, SystemName"
To disable:
WMIC PATH WIN32_NETWORKADAPTER WHERE "NETENABLED='FALSE'" CALL ENABLE
WMIC PATH WIN32_NETWORKADAPTER WHERE "NETENABLED='TRUE'" CALL ENABLE
Result:
```

[text](https://i.ibb.co/VVnScYw/image.png)

I tried for the other variables they have in common:

```
WMIC PATH WIN32_NETWORKADAPTER WHERE "Availability='3'" CALL DISABLE
WMIC PATH WIN32_NETWORKADAPTER WHERE "SystemName='SSALPHAMANAGER'" CALL DISABLE
WMIC PATH WIN32_NETWORKADAPTER WHERE "CreationClassName='Win32_NetworkAdapter'" CALL DISABLE
```

But the command returns with errors:

```
C:\Users\SSI.Marcelo>WMIC PATH WIN32_NETWORKADAPTER WHERE "Availability='3'" CALL DISABLE
Running (\\SSALPHAMANAGER\root\cimv2:Win32_NetworkAdapter.DeviceID="0")->DISABLE()
ERROR:
Description = Invalid method parameter(s)
```

Result:
[text](https://i.ibb.co/NKh5rFB/image.png)

Is there a way to make all adapters disabled, even those others that insist on remaining enabled?

This is the script I run to disable and enable network connections currently, I don't remember exactly where on the internet I copied part of it, but it works for adapters with an active connection...

```
@TITLE DISABLE AND RE-ENABLE ALL NETWORKS...
@ECHO OFF
Control.exe /name Microsoft.networkandSharingcenter
Start ncpa.cpl
CLS
@ECHO "...RESETTING NETWORKS... PLEASE WAIT..."
@ECHO          "...DISABLE NETWORKS..."
@ECHO OFF
WMIC PATH WIN32_NETWORKADAPTER WHERE "NETENABLED='TRUE'" CALL DISABLE >nul 2>&1
@ECHO OFF
WMIC PATH WIN32_NETWORKADAPTER WHERE "NETENABLED='FALSE'" CALL DISABLE >nul 2>&1
@ECHO OFF
@ECHO      "...ALL NETWORKS DISABLED..."
@ECHO     "...CLEARING NETWORK CACHES..."
@ECHO     "...NETWORK CACHES CLEANED!!!"
@ECHO OFF
IPCONFIG /FLUSHDNS >nul 2>&1
@ECHO OFF
TIMEOUT /T 3 >null 2>&1
CLS
@ECHO OFF
COLOR 2
ECHO.
ECHO.
@ECHO ...TO REACTIVATE THE NETWORKS AGAIN PRESS ENTER...
PAUSE >null 2>&1
CLS
@ECHO OFF
COLOR 9
@ECHO      "...REACTIVATING NETWORKS..."
@ECHO OFF
WMIC PATH WIN32_NETWORKADAPTER WHERE "NETENABLED='FALSE'" CALL ENABLE >nul 2>&1
@ECHO OFF
WMIC PATH WIN32_NETWORKADAPTER WHERE "NETENABLED='TRUE'" CALL ENABLE >nul 2>&1
@ECHO OFF
IPCONFIG /RELEASE >nul 2>&1
@ECHO OFF
IPCONFIG /RENEW >nul 2>&1
@ECHO OFF
TIMEOUT /T 3 >null 2>&1
CLS
COLOR AND
@ECHO      "...ALL NETWORKS ON!..."
@ECHO    "...LEAVING IN 3 SECONDS..."
@ECHO OFF
TIMEOUT /T 3 >null 2>&1
EXIT
```

Thanks for any help in advance.
Best Regards,
SS

Update:
Friends, I found the definitive solution for the Script above and I came to share it with you, the Script below has been improved and now it disables all network connections, Wired, Bluetooth, Wireless, Virtual, everything whether they are connected or not.

Code:

```
@Echo OFF
cd /d "%~dp0"
cd /d "%~dp0" && ( if exists "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ) && fsutil dirty query %systemdrive% 1>nul 2>nul || ( echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) : UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/k cd ""%~sdp0"" && %~s0 %params%", "", "runas ", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" && "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" && exit /B )
cls
@CHCP 1252>nul 2>&1
@TITLE DISABLE AND REACTIVATE ALL NETWORKS...
@ECHO OFF
Control.exe /name Microsoft.networkandSharingcenter
Start ncpa.cpl
CLS
@ECHO "...RESETTING NETWORKS... PLEASE WAIT..."
@ECHO "...DISABLE NETWORKS..."
@ECHO OFF
IPCONFIG /FLUSHDNS >nul 2>&1
@ECHO "...CLEARING NETWORK CACHES..."
@ECHO "...NETWORK CACHES CLEANED!!!"
@ECHO OFF
PnpUtil /Disable-Device /Class Net >nul 2>&1
@ECHO OFF
@ECHO "...ALL NETWORKS DISABLED..."
@ECHO OFF
TIMEOUT /T 3 >nul 2>&1
CLS
@ECHO OFF
COLOR 2
ECHO.
ECHO.
@ECHO ...TO REACTIVATE THE NETWORKS PRESS ENTER...
PAUSE >nul 2>&1
CLS
@ECHO OFF
COLOR 9
@ECHO "...REACTIVATING NETWORKS..."
@ECHO OFF
PnpUtil /Enable-Device /Class Net >nul 2>&1
@ECHO OFF
IPCONFIG /RELEASE >nul 2>&1
@ECHO OFF
IPCONFIG /RENEW >nul 2>&1
@ECHO OFF
TIMEOUT /T 3 >nul 2>&1
CLS
COLOR A
@ECHO "...ALL NETWORKS ACTIVATED!!!..."
@ECHO "...LEAVING IN 3 SECONDS..."
@ECHO OFF
TIMEOUT /T 3 >nul 2>&1
EXIT
```

Thanks again to everyone who collaborated in some way, especially to my friend @js2010, as it was through his tip that I was able to research and create this new Script, the definitive one to activate and deactivate all networks

Comment: `Disable-PnpDevice`

Comment: And could you show howto do it for all network PnpDevices with one command only?

Comment: I already found the answer using Powershell: ===> Disable: ===> Get-PnpDevice -Class "Net" | Disable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false - Enable: ===> Get-PnpDevice -Class "Net" | Enaable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false <====> Using Command Prompt Silently: ===> To disable ===> pnputil /Disable-device /Class Net >nul 2>&1 and To Enable ===> pnputil /Enable-device /Class Net >nul 2>&1

Comment: Some more powershell equivalents:  `(get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter -filter "netenabled='true'").enable()`